# limit a elements move in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

Hi i have a gif that moves around on random, but the thing is I don't want it to be able to move out of width 100% height 100%; 
, how can I avoid this?

html

```
<body>
    <div id='background'></div>
    <div id='waterfallframe'>
    <img src="waterfall.gif" id='waterfall'></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jquery

```
$("#waterfall").on({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).animate({
            left:(Math.random()*700)+"px",
            top:(Math.random()*700)+"px",
            width:"+=1px",
            height:"+=1px",
        },100);
    }
});
```

Comment: where is your html code???

Comment: When you say "frame", you mean the window? Anyway, you should simply multiply `Math.random()` times the width and height of the "frame" (minus the width and height of the image).

Comment: what you want to do is too ambiguous for a clear answer... you should consider making a jsfiddle to better illustrate what you want... that said, you could try messing with your Math.random()*700 to change where it can jump to (e.g. 30 + Math.random()*670 would still be within the same space but the 30 leftmost pixels would no longer be options for it to jump to)... there may well be simpler approaches but without more information about the structure of the page and a clearer understanding of what you are trying to do...

Comment: my javascript isn't that great... but from a purely math standpoint you would do something like left:(Math.random()*(window.innerWidth - $("#waterfall").clientWidth) and top:(Math.random()*(window.innerHeight - $("#waterfall").clientHeight)

Comment: @user3334690 write an answer, this is a good solution I think

Answer (score 0):

I don't do a whole lot in javascript so there may be cleaner ways of achieving this.

But looking at it from a math standpoint, what you want to do is limit the left and top values to ones that are within the screen.
You can get what those values would be by taking the screen width and subtracting the width of the image.

The calculations should look something like this:

```
left:(Math.random()*(window.innerWidth - $("#waterfall").clientWidth)
top:(Math.random()*(window.innerHeight - $("#waterfall").clientHeight)
```

If you wanted to test to see that this produces the desired result you could leave off the random part so that it looked something like:

```
left:((window.innerWidth - $("#waterfall").clientWidth)
top:((window.innerHeight - $("#waterfall").clientHeight)
```

This results in the image being in the maximum possible position generated by the random.

As a formula, for future use, it is something along the lines of:

```
minimumX + randomScaleFactorBetween0and1*(maximumX - minimumX - widthOfObject)
```

Hope that helps.